# curl: (58) could not load PEM client certificate, When cert is in program files

Tags: curl, filemaker

I have a curl request to an API using certs, If I put the cert on the C Drive anywhere accept the program files directory all works fine. But when I put the certs in the program files directory I get this error 
curl: (58) could not load PEM client certificate

You may suggest to not put the cert here but unfortunately I have to as I want to run a server side script using FileMaker to make the request. Server side scripting with FileMaker only has access to this directory 
C:\Program Files\FileMaker\FileMaker Server\Data\Documents

Is there some extra restriction different than other directories for program files dir, I've tried creating a test folder in program files and I still get the same error? I can write and read to this directory using curl but for some reason it can't seem to see the cert file

Comment: Mmm did I just break stackoverflow :-) or asked a question nobody can answer, yep I know this is quite obscure but if anybody has any ideas please share. I'm really stuck on this on

Answer (score 0):

So found the fix, if you put the executable cURL in the C:\Program Files\FileMaker\FileMaker Server\Data\Documents and then point your cURL expression to here it works.